# Access parent directive's controller scope variables in child directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two directives namely 'parent' and 'child'. I want to set visibility of child directive based on the value of a scope variable in parent directive's controller.

```
<div>
    <h1>Parent Directive selected index : {{ selectedIndex }}</h1>
    <div id="children" ng-transclude></div>
</div>
```

parent directive's controller has `selectedIndex` variable in its scope and child directive has `id` variable in its scope. I am trying to use `ng-show` on child directive using

```
<div ng-show="id==selectedIndex">
  <h1>{{id}}</h1>
</div>
```

It isn't working properly.

I am attaching a jsfiddle link of the scenario.

https://jsfiddle.net/vibhanshu/pep44qz7/10/

Comment: You forgot "" here <child id=1></child>

Comment: this question was already answered by this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a bidrectional property on your child directive `selectedIndex: '='`

```
scope: { id: '@', selectedIndex: '='}

<parent>
      <child id="1" selected-index="selectedIndex"></child>
      <child id="2" selected-index="selectedIndex"></child>
</parent>
```

Updated Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/pep44qz7/12/